# Return pointer on an array of lists?

Tags: c, arrays, list, pipe

I try to write a little shell. For this i want to implement a pipe function for numerous pipes. For this i try to break up a list of words at pipeflags in smaller lists, to generate argument-arrays for execvp() an link them later per pipes.

I use this code for generating the list array:

```
struct shellvalue* list2listarray(struct shellvalue* values, unsigned int* pipecount) {
struct shellvalue* orderarray = (struct shellvalue*) malloc((pipecount[0] + 1) * sizeof(struct shellvalue));
struct shellvalue* tmp;
tmp = *(&orderarray);
struct shellvalue* currentlist;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i <= *pipecount) {
    j = 0;
    while (values && !(values->ispipe)) {
        addtoken(values->word, j, &orderarray, &currentlist);
        values = values->next;
        j++;
    }if(values){
        values = values->next;
        orderarray++;
    }
    i++;
}
tmp ++;
return tmp;}
```

The addtocken method is implemented this way:

```
void addtoken(char* word, int counter, struct shellvalue** start,
    struct shellvalue** current) {
if (counter == 0) {
    size_t structsize = sizeof(struct shellvalue);
    struct shellvalue* tmp = (struct shellvalue*) malloc(structsize);
    tmp->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(tmp->word, word);
    *start = tmp;
    (*start)->next = NULL;
    *current = *start;
} else {
    struct shellvalue* new = (struct shellvalue*) malloc(
            sizeof(struct shellvalue));
    new->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(new->word, word);
    new->next = NULL;
    (*current)->next = new;
    *current = new;
}}
```

My problem is a classic pointer problem. I cant manage to give back a working pointer with my list2listarray-Method on my list-array, so i can easily switch through my lists. Can someone see the problem? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You know that the dereference operator `*` and the address-of operator `&` complements each other, and does, basically, the opposite things. That means the expression `*(&orderarray)` is the same as just `orderarray`.

Comment: Removing the casts, replacing the while-loops by for-loops and removing excessive parentheses would probably yield a more readable program. Also: I don't trust the recursive call , and `(*current)->next = new; *current = new;` looks wrong, too. the offset-1 indexing in  `while (i <= *pipecount) {` looks wrong, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `list2listarray` you pass the variable `orderarray` *by reference* (or as close as it can be in C) to the `addtoken` function, so when you do `*start = tmp` in the `addtoken` function you actually change the pointer in the `list2listarray` function as well, loosing your initial pointer you allocated there.

You also have a problem in `list2listarray` with your `tmp++` as that makes you loose the original pointer as well.

There is no need to pass this pointer "by reference" to the `addtoken` function, or to allocate there in the first place.

There are probably more problems related to your pointer use in the shown code, most likely leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I recommend you turn on more warnings by the compiler, as those are a good way to find possible places where you have undefined behavior, but don't just add casting as a way to shut the warnings up as it probably don't solve the actual root cause. And talking about casting, [don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).